В одном из циклов j < mas[i-1].length. Почему программа выводит ошибку, если написать j < mas.length, убрать [i-1]? Просто же написать j < mas.length
    *Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 0;
    String sS = "";
    
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        i++;
        sS = sS + sc.nextLine() + "/";*
    }
    
    String[] mas1 = sS.split("/");
    String[][] mas = new String[i][];
    for (int l = 0; l < i; l++)
        mas[l] = mas1[l].split(" ");
    
    for (int j = 0; j < mas[i-1].length; j++) {
        for (int k = mas.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            if (k != 0)
                System.out.print (mas[k][j] + " ");
            else
               System.out.println (mas[k][j]); 
        }
    }
    sc.close();


как задать хороший вопрос

Возможный дубликат вопроса Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?.

Воспользуйтесь отладкой кода ↑↑↑

Вопрос опишите подробно в основной части вопроса. В заголовке должен быть только короткий заголовок.
